# notify-keyspace-events in Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, redis, spring-session

I'd like to work with Redis for manipulating sessions.But I get failure when running the spring boot app.So I guess that this error is coming from maven dependencies especially version conflicts.

Here is my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

I tried to avoid notify-keyspace-events bug by integrating embedded-redis dependency in pom.xml but without success.

Notice that I added two dependencies in above pom.xml which there artifactId are spring-session-data-redis and lettuce-core.These dependencies are respectively responsible for Redis connection and ensuring thread safety for session connections.

Below the config class for redis http session:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(); 
    }

}
```

Also I configured http session management by using spring-session in below component:

```
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionStrategy;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        //some code here
        public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
                return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
            }
    }
```

But when I run spring boot app, I get this following runtime error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.BookStoreApplication.main(BookStoreApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:257) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceServerCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceServerCommands.java:571) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceServerCommands.setConfig(LettuceServerCommands.java:332) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.setConfig(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:1126) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:70) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:286) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:118) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:109) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:598) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:556) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:508) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:563) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

Please any help is very appreciated.Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Check this issue at github spring-session repo : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/113

Comment: I have checked the issue in your proposed link but without success

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have this issue:

> io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events

then add following configuration class in your application:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfigureAction {
    @Bean
    public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }
}
```

Comment: this solved my issue ,please explain what does you codes mean? @Atui

Comment: this does solve my issue, can you explain this a little bit?

Comment: See this issue for more of the background and explanation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/124#issuecomment-71490616

Comment: I didn't need to configure a `ConfigureRedisAction` bean when the Redis cluster was not using encryption.  Now that the Redis cluster IS using encryption, why is this bean suddenly necessary?  What is it about adding encryption that causes this behavior?

Comment: @JackStraw it has nothing to do with encryption, but the same version that added encryption also added users and ACLs. If you use those to prevent the client from calling `CONFIG` then you get this error.

Answer (score 3):

In my case - I had misconfigured lettuce client with client config for standalone server connecting to sentinel node. When I have changed client configuration of sentinel connecting to sentinel node exception went away.

FYI when using `ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP` you have to have configure Redis redis.conf file with `config set notify-keyspace-events Egx`. See [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/notifications#configuration) and default implementation of `ConfigureRedisAction` at [Spring session source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java#L56).

Answer (score 0):

Set these parameters in the property

```
spring:
  session:
    redis:
      configure-action: none
```